# What is this operation called in functional programming?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, pipeline, naming-conventions, naming

I just wrote a function with this type in TypeScript. It seems like a useful pattern for use in pipelining, etc. -- it certainly simplified the code I was working on. I would intend to overload this for three or more functions as well.

`<T,A1,A2>(fs: [(t: T) => A1, (t: T) => A2]) => (t: T) => [A1, A2]`

I'm progressing in my knowledge about functional programming but am somewhat lacking in theory and background.

I'd like to use an idiomatic name for this operation.

I can think of two analogues:

- The UNIX `tee` tool has a somewhat analogous design but only works
  (and the name only makes sense) for two functions.
- The construct is a little bit like `Promise.all` but I'm not sure
  "all" is a very good name for it either (though it's at least not
  misleading, and might feel right to people with
  JavaScript/TypeScript backgrounds specifically).

What is this construct called?

Comment: I don't know that this has a single canonical name; [this Hoogle search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20(b%2C%20c)) returns things like "lifted pairing", "fanout to pair" and "fork".  I don't know if there's a canonical-enough answer for SO.

Comment: I found [fanout](https://gigobyte.github.io/purify/adts/Tuple/#static-fanout) again?  Still not sure

Comment: @jcalz, I agree, it looks like 'fanout': https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-